# My validate form function doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, background-color

I have set up a `validateForm()` function with a lot of if's in it. Because all error-giving fields have to be colored red when the submit button is pressed, I decided to try the following in my JavaScript:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var i = 0;

    var a = document.forms["MyForm"]["Naam"].value;
    if(a == null || a == "")
    {
        i++;
        ctrl.style.backgroundColor = #FF0000;
    }

    //alot more if statements like the above

    if(i > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But when I click on the submit button, the fields don't get colored. If I put an alert statement in the first if, it will give an alert when the field is empty on submit. So the validating functions all work. But the coloring won't. Does anyone know how, or could anyone help me a bit in the right direction?

Comment: How/when do you call the function `validateForm`?

Comment: `ctrl.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";` should do the trick.

Comment: `ctrl` is not defined anywhere here. That might not be a problem, but check your console for errors.

Comment: `#FF0000;` should be `"#FF0000";` (around quotes) and what's `ctrl`?

Comment: @Butt4cak3 I refer to the validateForm() function in the from tag in my html "onsubmit= return validateForm()"

Comment: Okay, I did some research on how to color the background of fields, but appearantly ctrl refers to the fields in that code that would have been colored. I should change ctrl for the id's of the fields that I want to be colored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function checkme_station() 
{
    stationObj = document.getElementById('station_name');
    if (stationObj.value == "")
    {
        stationObj.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
        alert("Please enter a name for this station.");
        stationObj.focus();
        return false;
    }

    selectionObj = document.getElementById('selection');
    if (selectionObj.value == "Enter song or musician name" || selectionObj.value == "")
    {
        selectionObj.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
        alert("Please enter the name of the song or name of musician into selection field.");
        selectionObj.focus();
        return false;
    }

    stationObj.style.borderColor = '';
    selectionObj.style.borderColor = '';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this, I'm sure this would work! But since I'm just a beginning programmer I prefer not to use functions I do not know yet. With the comment on my own question above I have just completen my problem myself! But thanks for the effort :)